# Google maps and Google earth application

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I want to develop an application to find the value of a property based on some constants(such as the distance from the shore,the width of the road in frond of the property,the neighborhood that is located to etc) -constants that i will have to insert to that application (i guess with some tool that can make kml files with point,lines,areas and geocoding information) and variables which i will have τo take from the user through a series of forms.To succesfully calculate a value i need to make spatial querys (such as which is the distance of a point from that polygon?)

Is it possible to develop such an app with google maps or google earth or i have to develop with the use of an GIS(ESRI,Manifold etc).Also which is the difference between the possibilities of the resulting apps with maps and earth?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bill Chadwick has [some Javascript](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGeo.js) for Google Maps that calculates the distance of a point from a poly. See the the bottom of [this page](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGmapBits.htm).